# Changing HTML elements from Drop Down List value using Javascript DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, select, switch-statement

Firstly, I'm very new to Javascript, so I'm sorry if this is an easy question.
My goal is to display the result of my switch statement in the  tag. For now, I'm just trying to console.log it, but I can't seem to get it to work. My difficulty seems to be in storing the value from the drop down list in a variable that I can use in my switch statement. Here is what I've tried:

```js
var behaviour = document.getElementById("behaviour");
var kentsBehaviour = behaviour.value;

console.log(kentsBehaviour)

//var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

function kentsReward (kentsBehaviour) {
  var prize;

  switch (kentsBehaviour) {
    case "Really good":
      prize = "You get foot rubs!";
      break;

    case "Good":
      prize = "You get an Oreo";
      break;

    case "Medium":
      prize = "You get bread";
      break;

    case "Not so good":
      prize = "You don't get anything";
      break;

    case "Greer":
      prize = "You get pinches";
      break;

    default:
      return "Tell me how you behaved today";
  }

  console.log( prize);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Kent's Rewards</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Please select your behaviour for today:</h1>
  <select name="behaviour" id="behaviour" onChange="kentsReward()">
    <option value="default">Select your behaviour</option>
    <option value="Really good">Really good</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Not so good">Not so good</option>
    <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
    <option value="Greer">Greer</option>
  </select>
  <h2>Your reward is:</h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change your `HTML` to this: `onChange="kentsReward(this.value)"`, inline event handlers are discouraged now a days, you should switch to using `document.getElementById("behaviour").addEventListener("change", function(){ kentsReward(this.value); });` `this` refers to the drop down list inside of the `event handler function` so you then pass it's `value` to your `function`. You can remove the first 3 lines of code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tag. If is the <h3></h3>, just put an id on the tag, and then do `getElementById("tagId").innerHtml = kentsReward(kentsBehaviour)`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the addEventListener approach before as well, what I was missing was the this.value part.
As for the <h3> innerHTML, where do I put this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined `kentsReward(*parameter*)` that takes a parameter. You not passing anything when it called at select tag.Try to pass current value of select field like `<select name="behaviour" id="behaviour" onChange="kentsReward(this.value)">`

Comment: Thank you. The this.value feature is what I was missing. Here's the solution I came up with: https://github.com/cipdv/kentrewards